# How to enter a special character as a Password in the JTextField of the swing component?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jpasswordfield

When we enter password in any account the characters are not shown to us.  I created a JTextField whose label is "password".  What can I do so that when I enter characters in this JTextField they are shown like `"***********"` ?

Comment: Try [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html).

Answer (score 9):

Don't use a normal `JTextField`, use a `JPasswordField`.

- [How to Use Password Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html)

Comment: Also note that JPasswordField has a `setEchorChar(char)` method which lets you choose the character which gets displayed in place of the typing, and you can set it to zero to enable display of the actual typed characters. Handy if you want to offer a "show typing" checkbox for the user.

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution to the problem is using `JPasswordField`

**See this documentation:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html

**See these tutorials:**

www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240_*Swing/0300*_JPasswordField.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use JPasswordField but you can use this code to convert Char to String;

String password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField.getPassword());